# Insert a Coldfusion struct into a database

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

If I wanted to save a contact form submission to the database, how can I insert the form scope in as the submission? It's been some time since I used Coldfusion.

The contact forms vary depending on what part of the site it was submitted from, so it needs to scale and handle a form with 5 fields or one with 10 fields. I just want to store the data in a blob table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most space efficient way and least complicated to turn back into original shape is using serializeJSON. After that, you can use something like key:value|key:value, or XML representation of your struct.

Comment: Okay, I used that function and was able to pass it to a CFC to insert it into my table. I can see the data in the database, but now CF sits at 'Waiting...' after I submit the form. What is causing it to hang?

Comment: ? using ajax form submit?  Debug with Firebug.  It shouldn't hang.

Answer (score 2):

Cfwddx is also an alternative.

Comment: And you vote me down for that?  It's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: A little strong!  The fact it gives you XML could be far more useful in other server side languages, rather than this new fangled JSON :)

Comment: I don't know, WDDX is like Flash Form.  They are there for backward compatibility reason only.  We should not promote the use of them anymore.  Agree?

Comment: even though i side with henry that wddx shouldn't be used any more, i will say that whatever gets the job done trumps "what you are suppose to do" every time. if you're using a sql server database that have a column of xml, then in this situation i would say that using wddx would be faster and less error prone then creating your own xml transformation script.

Comment: @rip747 wouldn't toXML() - http://cflib.org/udf/toXML better than the heavy WDDX?

Comment: @henry - could be. however i would rather use wddx if you need to convert cfml types to xml as it's tried and proven. not to mention that is a native tag ;)

Comment: @rip747 storing WDDX in XML column?  That's a use case I've never really thought of.  Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't normalize the form fields into proper table(s), you can try storing them:

- in XML (SQL Server supports XML pretty well), or
- in JSON (in a plain varchar field), or
- `ObjectLoad()` & `ObjectSave()` (CF9 only) to store as blob.

IIRC there are ways to get object load/save functionality in pre-CF9 by tapping into Java.  http://www.riaforge.org/ or http://cflib.org/ might have it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is a way to store a native structure into a database, but have you thought about using JSON to represent your object as key-pair values and then parsing it into a native structure after retrieving it from the database?

There are tags/functions out there that will help you with the encoding and decoding into JSON:

- [cfJSON Tag](http://www.epiphantastic.com/cfjson/)
- [CF8 Serialize JSON](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_s_03.html)
- [CF8 Deserialize JSON](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/functions_c-d_43.html#5176845)

Comment: Since you're using CF8, just use SerializeJSON() / DeserizlieJSON().  No need to use 3rd party library.

Comment: I agree, I merely referenced for the off-chance the asker had CF7 or lower. Otherwise, those functions are the way to go.